# Vectorizing a function with mapply

Tags: r, function, vectorization

I have a function in R which takes strings which represent commerce discount structures and converts them into numerical multipliers.  For example, the string "50/20/15" just means that the original price gets 50% off, then another 20% off, then another 15% off. This will be equivalent to multiplying the original price by (1 - 0.50)*(1 - 0.20)(1 - 0.15), which equals  0.34.

My function is as follows.

```
disc_str_to_num <- function(string){
  numstrings <- strsplit(string,"/")
  nums <- mapply(as.numeric, numstrings)
  prod(1 - nums/100)
}
```

which works as desired on single strings.

```
> disc_str_to_num("50/20/15")
[1] 0.34
```

Unfortunately this fails for string vectors.

```
discount_vec <- c("50/10",
                  "50/10/10",
                  "50/10/15",
                  "50/10/20")

> disc_str_to_num(discount_vec)
Error in nums/100 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I have tried various applications of the `Vectorize` function, with no success.

How may I modify my function to work for string vectors?  The expected output is a numeric vector of the component-wise values of the string vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Vectorize like this:

```
Vectorize(disc_str_to_num)(discount_vec)
##    50/10 50/10/10 50/10/15 50/10/20 
##   0.4500   0.4050   0.3825   0.3600
```

or create a new function name and then invoke it:

```
disc_str_to_num_vec <- Vectorize(disc_str_to_num)

disc_str_to_num_vec(discount_vec)
##    50/10 50/10/10 50/10/15 50/10/20 
##   0.4500   0.4050   0.3825   0.3600
```

or rewrite the function as shown. Note that strsplit creates a one element list in this function and [[1]] takes the contents.

```
disc_str_to_num_vec2 <- 
  Vectorize(function(x) prod(1 - as.numeric(strsplit(x, "/")[[1]]) / 100))

disc_str_to_num_vec2(discount_vec)
##    50/10 50/10/10 50/10/15 50/10/20 
##   0.4500   0.4050   0.3825   0.3600
```

Answer (score 1):

The `prod` should be also within the loop

```
sapply(strsplit(discount_vec, "/"), \(x) prod(1 - as.numeric(x)/100))
[1] 0.4500 0.4050 0.3825 0.3600
```

---

For a single element, `mapply` use `SIMPLIFY = TRUE` and thus we don't have any issue, however with more than one element, it returns a `list` and thus the last step doesn't work

```
> list(c(1, 3), c(2, 4))/100
Error in list(c(1, 3), c(2, 4))/100 : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

If we use the OP's code, then wrap with another `mapply` (or could do this in the same `mapply` as showed with `sapply`)

```
> disc_str_to_num <- function(string){
+   numstrings <- strsplit(string,"/")
+   nums <- mapply(as.numeric, numstrings)
+   mapply(\(x) prod(1 - x/100), nums)
+ }
> 
> disc_str_to_num(discount_vec)
[1] 0.4500 0.4050 0.3825 0.3600
```

---

Another option would be to read as `data.frame` with `read.table`, and then use `rowProds` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
rowProds(as.matrix(1- read.table(text = discount_vec,
  header = FALSE, sep = "/", fill = TRUE)/100), na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 0.4500 0.4050 0.3825 0.3600
```